# In Flutter/Dart, how to separate between alphabeth and numeric in a single string into array?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example:

- `"X84J25"` --> `<dynamic>[ "X", 84, "J", 25 ]`
- `"96KGWWA3"` --> `<dynamic> [ 96, "KGWWA", 3 ]`
- `"L8273BB"` --> `<dynamic> [ "L", 8273, "BB" ]`
- `"C"` --> `<dynamic> [ "C" ]`
- `"92123"` --> `<dynamic> [ 92123 ]`

This is sort of function `split`, but while split has a clear separator defined (like space for example), this is separated by flip flop between alphabet to numeric to alphabet again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split does not really work here but you can do something like this instead using a regular expression to capture multiple matches in your string input:

```
void main() {
  print(weirdSplit("X84J25")); // [X, 84, J, 25]
  print(weirdSplit("X84J25").map((dynamic e) => e.runtimeType));
  // (String, int, String, int)

  print(weirdSplit("96KGWWA3")); // [96, KGWWA, 3]
  print(weirdSplit("L8273BB")); // [L, 8273, BB]
  print(weirdSplit("C")); // [C]
  print(weirdSplit("92123")); // [92123]
}

List<dynamic> weirdSplit(String input) => <dynamic>[
      ...RegExp(r'\d+|\D+')
          .allMatches(input)
          .map((match) => match[0]!)
          .map((string) => int.tryParse(string) ?? string)
    ];
```

Comment: Ooh, very neat solution, using regex. I'm not very familiar with regex, so I'll study your solution. Thanks!!

Comment: @ChenLiYong The pattern `\d+|\D+` means that a match should contain either "one or multiple digits (`\d+`)" or "one or more non-digit letters (`\D+`)". We are then asking Dart to find all matches of this rule. Since it is greedy, it will try make a group as large as possible before ending the group. The next group is then found from where the previous group ended and forward. This continues until the end of our input.

Comment: the "greedy" means the "+" part right? yes, and I'm also learning from here that you can use regex to scan and get matches, instead of just to validate whether a string follows a regex. Usually, I use copy-pasted regex to check if an email or URL entered is valid, but never for extracting contents like this. Thanks.

Comment: @ChenLiYong No, the greedy is default. The `+` means we want one or more (`*` would mean zero or more). Not greedy would be `\d+?|\D+?` where we tell the regular expression engine that it should try make the groups as small as possible. You can try use it and see how it changes the output of my example. But I highly recommend finding some basic tutorial about regular expression since just a basic understanding can help you solve a lot of problems. :)

Comment: yes, I admit I have already tried to learn regex, sometimes toying using regex builder, but building even simplest regex like to check whether a string is a valid date was a nightmare. xD thanks for the explanation.